# Archiving Reports SQL 2005 Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Is there a way to configure the Report Server to Archive the reports to the Report Server or to a path on the File System.

I need to save the reports generated as .pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a subscription that "delivers" to a windows file share. Check out the subscriptions tab in Report Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "Report History"?

Here's how you create Report History:

1. In Report Manager, select the report
   for which you want history and view
   the report.
2. Click the Properties tab for that
   report.
3. Click the History link in the left
   margin.
4. Ensure the "Allow History to be
   Created Manually" checkbox is
   checked.

Select the History tab: to create an instance of Report History, click the New Snapshot icon.

See also: [Managing Report History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155849(SQL.90).aspx)